# Challenges with conditions

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, dice

Hello I am new to Java and this is what I have to do:
I have to make a point game and I am not posting the entire thing as it is irrelevant. There are two diсes, one with 6 sides and the other with 9 sides. This is what I have a problem with:

If you roll double 6’s at least 5 times in a single round, the following will     occur:

- The dice are rolled a random number of times (between 10 and 30 times)
- The cumulative product of all those dice rolls are added to the bank

I don't really understand the wording here and I have done the whole program except for this part. This is what I have done:

```
if (ninedice == 6 && sixdice == 6 >= 5){
    ninedice = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random () * (30-10)+ 10);
    sixdice = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random () * (30-10)+10);
    accountpoints = ninedice+sixdice;
}
```

This is obviously not correct and I am not getting the desired result as it just does not roll the die a random number of times and does not add points in the account either. ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED AND THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Have you learned about loops yet?

Comment: a little bit yes but not advanced loops

Comment: And when it asks for the product of all the rolls, does that include the double sixes?

Comment: It doesnt specify that but yes

Comment: I understand, does my answer address your concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're on the right track but not quite there yet. The if statement condition should just be `if (ninedice == 6 && sixdice == 6)`. No need for the `>= 5` part. This if statement signifies indicates whether or not the first roll for each die reuslts in a 6. However, the if-statement body has some logic issues. 
This body of code,

```
ninedice = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random () * (30-10)+ 10);
sixdice = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random () * (30-10)+10);
```

generates the number of times the two die are going to be rolled again. However, `ninedice` and `sixdice` represent the first rolls so don't overwrite them. Replace it with,

```
int ninedicerolls = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random () * (30-10)+ 10);
int sixdicerolls = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random () * (30-10)+10);
```

Now keep a product variable to keep track of each roll for each die,

```
int ninediceproduct = ninedice;
int sixdiceproduct = sixdice;
while(ninediceproduct > 0){
    ninediceproduct *= (int) Math.ceil(Math.random () * (9-1)+ 1);
    ninediceproduct--;
}
while(sixdiceproduct > 0){
    sixdiceproduct *= (int) Math.ceil(Math.random () * (6-1)+ 1);
    sixdiceproduct--;
}
```

Then, multiply the products together,

```
int cumulative = sixdiceproduct * ninediceproduct;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something more like this:

```
rollDice();

if (nineDice == 6 && sixDice == 6)
{
  myDiceCondition++;
}

if (myDiceCondition >= 5)
{
  // get random number between 10 and 30
  // loop for that amount
    // roll both dice
    // add to account balance?
}
```

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is evaluating to: (true/false && true/false >= 5). You need to compare 5 to an int. Are you keeping track of the number of times that double 6's are rolled? Something like this should work:

```
public static void diceExample(){

    int ninedice, sixdice, accountpoints, rolledDoubleSix;

    if (ninedice == 6 && sixdice == 6) {
        rolledDoubleSix++;
    }

    if (rolledDoubleSix == 5){
        ninedice=(int)Math.ceil(Math.random () * (30-10)+ 10);
        sixdice=(int)Math.ceil(Math.random () * (30-10)+10);
        accountpoints = ninedice+sixdice;

    }
}
```